# Reference specific checkbox in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a GridView which show data retrived from database. I've made TemplateField (CheckBox) to GridView with this code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="dbRecordsContent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dbRecordsContent_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="myCheckBox" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="title" SortExpression="title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="url" HeaderText="url" SortExpression="url" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="category" HeaderText="category" SortExpression="category" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="isChecked" HeaderText="isChecked" SortExpression="isChecked" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

My grid view looks like this:

[image]

My question is: How do I know which checkbox ID is checked? For example:

I want to delete 2nd row when I press "Delete" button. Of course I will check second Checkbox, but how do I know which record to delete? How to reference second checkbox in a code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your delete button's click event handler you need to loop through all the rows in the grid and if a check box is checked, then you need to perform your delete logic, like this:

```
protected void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(GridViewRow row in dbRecordsContent.Rows)
    {
        // Only look for check boxes in data rows, ignoring header 
        // and footer rows
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (((CheckBox)row.FindControl("myCheckBox")).Checked)
            {
                // Do delete logic here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

To get the row number use the `GridViewRow.RowIndex` property, like this:

```
int rowNumber = row.RowIndex;
```

Read [GridViewRow.RowIndex Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowindex.aspx) for more information.

Comment: It works perfect. One more question. How do I get checked row number?

Comment: @rootpanthera - see `UPDATE:` in answer.

Comment: Hmm, actually I found out that it doesn't work as it should. It works only if last checkbox in a row is selected (true statement above). Else statement is always executed even if any other checkbox is checked. Any idea why?

Comment: What `else` statement, I don't have an `else` statement in the code I posted?

Comment: Yep it was my bad. I mixed up something. Your code is perfect. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
<asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="myCheckBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                       oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

code side,

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = ((GridViewRow)((CheckBox)sender).NamingContainer);
    int index = row.RowIndex;
    CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)Gridview.Rows[index].FindControl("myCheckBox");
    string checkboxstatus;
    if (cb1.Checked)
    {
      //write your code
    }        
    else
    {
      //write your code
    }
}
```